# Spotfire : Weighted Percentage Calculation in BarChart

Tags: bar-chart, percentage, spotfire

I have this set of data :

```
Kind     Weight  
A        3  
A        3
A        3
B        2
B        2
C        1
```

I would like to create a Spotfire barchart representing the contribution of distinct **Kind** column values. The expression provided by Spotfire in this case is :

```
Count() / THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))
```

But I would like to divide this by the value of the **Weight** column. As Spotfire asks for an aggregating method I tried this unsuccessfully :

```
Count() / First([Weight]) THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))
```

For the record, I am not using a calculated value because my purpose is to have a dynamic BarChart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what would your expected results look like? Can you attach the bar chart showing what it is rendering compared to what your desired output is?

Comment: I would like to have a bar chart where in my exemple A, B and C have the same value which is 33%.  The 3 occurences of A are divided by their weight, also for B and C. Currently, A is at 50%, B at 33% and C at 17%

Comment: Well C is 1 so 1/1 is 100%... how would that be 33%? A should be 33 and B should be 50... how do you get 33 for all of them?

Comment: Let me detail my computation : C is 1/1, B is 2/2, A is 3/3 so each one is at 33%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your desired logic, you can use this on your `VALUE AXIS` of your Bar Chart:

```
UniqueCount([Kind]) / UniqueCount([Kind]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))
```

This will work unless the `Weight` doesn't equal the `Count of Kind`

If your `Weight` could change, for example if `Kind A` had a weight of `2` instead of `3` but still had `3` rows, you can accomplish your logic by doing this:

1. Insert a calculated column: `Count([Kind]) OVER ([Kind]) / Max([Weight]) OVER ([Kind])`. Name this column `WeightedWeight`
2. Use this formula on the `VALUE AXIS` of your bar chart `Max([WeightedWeight]) / UniqueCount([Kind])  OVER (All([Axis.X]))`

Comment: Your solution with the calculated the works just fine. Thank your very much for your help and patience

Comment: No problem at all. I was confused at first because your problem was quite abstract, but glad I could help. Be sure to accept correct answers on all your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers